# Reference on double perturbation theory?

Tags: reference-request, perturbation-theory

I have a system that depends on three perturbations:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x;\epsilon,\mu,\eta)$$

The $\epsilon$ perturbation is independent of the other ones, but $\mu,\eta$ have a joint interaction I want to analyze using perturbation theory. However, most of the references I have only use perturbation with one parameter.

Is there a good reference that studies the case where you have more than one parameter? My current main reference is Holmes 1995 Introduction to Perturbation Methods

Comment: Landau Lifshitz “Mechanics” 3rd edition is a solid reference